How to set up CloudWatch Alarm for AutoScalinGroup > dynamic scaling (used in ECS)
I have created an ECS cluster, and deployed a 2-container task using a Service (during Service create I associate the Application Load Balancer - using target group of type IP - to it),
this works fine (I can access my DNS URL and it loads as expected).
I am now trying to use an AutoScalingGroup for automatically scaling instances (cluster autoscaling), based on CPU utilization.
I have created the ASG (desired instance count=1, max=4), but now need to create a dynamic scaling policy, based on CPU utilization.
If average instance CPU usage is over 50%, I want the ASG to add more instances using simple scaling.
(and if ave usage falls under 40, scale back in to min desired count again).

When I click on Create Cloudwatch alarm I get the following: Step 1 (I then click 'Select Metric'):

My question is basically - what metric do I need to select to achieve the above CPU usage scaling?

Update: OK thanks Mark, I have added that alarm.
The service runs, (with ASG + autoscaling alarm set to increase instance by 1 when ave CPU goes over 50), I access my endpoint (runs ok, this is a CPU load demo app which basically runs fibonacci sequence, n=5 runs fine):
When I set n=60 (loads up CPU usage big time!), I get following:
-app/url crashes with 504 gateway timeout. It never recovers (even with closing it and opening new tabs to it)
-CPU usage metrics on cluster:


alarm data (created above, attached to dynamic scaling policy used by ASG):

-yet, no extra instances/tasks are being created on my cluster (simply remains at 1):


OK my alarm was in "insufficient data" state (not in "In Alarm" state) which is strange (set it to use missing data=breach, now it is triggering):
Now the ASG is at least trying to do something, but have a bizarre new error:

Why would a particular instance type not be available in a Availability Zone (but is available in others...doesn't seem to make sense)
OK i removed the eu-west-1a from the ASG's launch template and now something is happening (instances being created):

but my Tasks on my cluster remain at 1 (and the app url is still unresponsive):


In the metrics console, click ECS, then click ClusterName, ServiceName, then select the metric in the list that has your cluster name, sevice name, and also a Metric name of CPUUtilization
